# Error creating publishing page: The file Pages/test.aspx has been modified by Domain\Username on 03 Aug 2011 11:20:12 -0400

Tags: error, publishing-page

Here is some background on the environment

- SharePoint 2010 with a content database that was upgraded from SharePoint 2007
- The site was created using a Custom site template
- Pages created in the Pages library are using a custom Page Layout and Content Type

When I try to create a new publishing page I SOMETIMES get the error below.  I'm very confused because this doesn't happen consistently!  Sometimes the page is created successfully and sometimes I get the error!  What is going on?

Error

The file Pages/test.aspx has been modified by Domian\Username on 03 Aug 2011 11:20:12 -0400.

Troubleshoot issues with Microsoft SharePoint Foundation.

Correlation ID: 1b4a27ec-d7ef-4eca-93ea-56858b5c2531

Date and Time: 8/3/2011 11:20:12 AM

Go back to site

In the SharePoint logs I see this

08/03/2011 11:20:12.36  w3wp.exe (0x0DB4)                        0x1AB0 SharePoint Foundation          General                        8kh7 High     0x81020015The file Pages/test.aspx has been modified by Domain\Username on 03 Aug 2011 11:20:12 -0400. 1b4a27ec-d7ef-4eca-93ea-56858b5c2531

08/03/2011 11:20:12.36  w3wp.exe (0x0DB4)                        0x1AB0 SharePoint Foundation          General                        8e2r Medium   Possible mismatch between the reported error with code = 0x81070901 and message: "The file Pages/test.aspx has been modified by Domain\Username on 03 Aug 2011 11:20:12 -0400." and the returned error with code 0x81020037. 1b4a27ec-d7ef-4eca-93ea-56858b5c2531

08/03/2011 11:20:12.36  w3wp.exe (0x0DB4)                        0x1AB0 Web Content Management         Publishing                     a5y6 Exception A critical error occurred while creating a PublishingPage through PublishingWeb.AddPublishingPage(string, PageLayout, SPFolder). Microsoft.SharePoint.SPException: The file Pages/test.aspx has been modified by Domain\Username on 03 Aug 2011 11:20:12 -0400. ---> System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException (0x81020037): 0x81020015The file Pages/test.aspx has been modified by Domain\Username on 03 Aug 2011 11:20:12 -0400.     at Microsoft.SharePoint.Library.SPRequestInternalClass.AddOrUpdateItem(String bstrUrl, String bstrListName, Boolean bAdd, Boolean bSystemUpdate, Boolean bPreserveItemVersion, Boolean bUpdateNoVersion, Int32& plID, String& pbstrGuid, Guid pbstrNewDocId, Boolean bHasNewDocId, String bstrVersion, Object& pvarAttachmentNames, ... 1b4a27ec-d7ef-4eca-93ea-56858b5c2531

08/03/2011 11:20:12.36* w3wp.exe (0x0DB4)                        0x1AB0 Web Content Management         Publishing                     a5y6 Exception ...Object& pvarAttachmentContents, Object& pvarProperties, Boolean bCheckOut, Boolean bCheckin, Boolean bMigration, Boolean bPublish, String bstrFileName, ISP2DSafeArrayWriter pListDataValidationCallback, ISP2DSafeArrayWriter pRestrictInsertCallback, ISP2DSafeArrayWriter pUniqueFieldCallback)     at Microsoft.SharePoint.Library.SPRequest.AddOrUpdateItem(String bstrUrl, String bstrListName, Boolean bAdd, Boolean bSystemUpdate, Boolean bPreserveItemVersion, Boolean bUpdateNoVersion, Int32& plID, String& pbstrGuid, Guid pbstrNewDocId, Boolean bHasNewDocId, String bstrVersion, Object& pvarAttachmentNames, Object& pvarAttachmentContents, Object& pvarProperties, Boolean bCheckOut, Boolean bCheckin, Boolean bMigration, Boolean bPublish, String bstrFileName, ISP2DSafeArrayWriter pListDataValidationCa... 1b4a27ec-d7ef-4eca-93ea-56858b5c2531

08/03/2011 11:20:12.36* w3wp.exe (0x0DB4)                        0x1AB0 Web Content Management         Publishing                     a5y6 Exception ...llback, ISP2DSafeArrayWriter pRestrictInsertCallback, ISP2DSafeArrayWriter pUniqueFieldCallback)     --- End of inner exception stack trace ---     at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPGlobal.HandleComException(COMException comEx)     at Microsoft.SharePoint.Library.SPRequest.AddOrUpdateItem(String bstrUrl, String bstrListName, Boolean bAdd, Boolean bSystemUpdate, Boolean bPreserveItemVersion, Boolean bUpdateNoVersion, Int32& plID, String& pbstrGuid, Guid pbstrNewDocId, Boolean bHasNewDocId, String bstrVersion, Object& pvarAttachmentNames, Object& pvarAttachmentContents, Object& pvarProperties, Boolean bCheckOut, Boolean bCheckin, Boolean bMigration, Boolean bPublish, String bstrFileName, ISP2DSafeArrayWriter pListDataValidationCallback, ISP2DSafeArrayWriter pRestrictInsertCallback, ISP2DSafeArrayWri... 1b4a27ec-d7ef-4eca-93ea-56858b5c2531

08/03/2011 11:20:12.36* w3wp.exe (0x0DB4)                        0x1AB0 Web Content Management         Publishing                     a5y6 Exception ...ter pUniqueFieldCallback)     at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPListItem.AddOrUpdateItem(Boolean bAdd, Boolean bSystem, Boolean bPreserveItemVersion, Boolean bNoVersion, Boolean bMigration, Boolean bPublish, Boolean bCheckOut, Boolean bCheckin, Guid newGuidOnAdd, Int32& ulID, Object& objAttachmentNames, Object& objAttachmentContents, Boolean suppressAfterEvents, String filename)     at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPListItem.UpdateInternal(Boolean bSystem, Boolean bPreserveItemVersion, Guid newGuidOnAdd, Boolean bMigration, Boolean bPublish, Boolean bNoVersion, Boolean bCheckOut, Boolean bCheckin, Boolean suppressAfterEvents, String filename)     at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPListItem.SystemUpdate()     at Microsoft.SharePoint.Publishing.PublishingWeb.<>c_*DisplayClass1c.b*_17()     at Micr... 1b4a27ec-d7ef-4eca-93ea-56858b5c2531

08/03/2011 11:20:12.36* w3wp.exe (0x0DB4)                        0x1AB0 Web Content Management         Publishing                     a5y6 Exception ...osoft.Office.Server.Diagnostics.FirstChanceHandler.ExceptionFilter(Boolean fRethrowException, TryBlock tryBlock, FilterBlock filter, CatchBlock catchBlock, FinallyBlock finallyBlock) 1b4a27ec-d7ef-4eca-93ea-56858b5c2531
08/03/2011 11:20:12.36  w3wp.exe (0x0DB4)                        0x1AB0 SharePoint Server              Unified Logging Service        c91s Monitorable Watson bucket parameters: SharePoint Server 2010, ULSException14, 81eed5e0 "web content management", 0e00129b "14.0.4763.0", 1f65804a "microsoft.sharepoint", 0e00129a "14.0.4762.0", 4bad8a7a "sat mar 27 00:32:58 2010", 00003a3c "00003a3c", 00000027 "00000027", 6ded0494 "spexception:81020037", 61357936 "a5y6" 1b4a27ec-d7ef-4eca-93ea-56858b5c2531

08/03/2011 11:20:12.36  w3wp.exe (0x0DB4)                        0x1AB0 Web Content Management         Publishing                     a5yd Unexpected A critical error occurred while creating PublishingPage 'test.aspx' through PublishingWeb.AddPublishingPage(string, PageLayout, SPFolder). Exception The file Pages/test.aspx has been modified by Domain\Username on 03 Aug 2011 11:20:12 -0400. 1b4a27ec-d7ef-4eca-93ea-56858b5c2531

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There were no custom Event Receivers on the Pages library.  There were however the following Microsoft event receivers on the Pages Library that I can see by using SharePoint Manager 2010

Microsoft.Office.RecordsManagement.PolicyFeatures.ExpirationEventReceiver

- ItemAdded (Asynchronous)
- ItemAdded (Synchronous)
- ItemUpdated (Asynchronous)
- ItemUpdated (Synchronous)
- ItemCheckedIn (Asynchronous)
- ItemCheckedIn (Synchronous)
- ItemUncheckedOut (Asynchronous)
- ItemUncheckedOut (Synchronous)
- ItemFileMoved (Synchronous)

I can see that all the Asynchronous event handlers have an assembly version of 12.0.0.0 and all the Synchronous event handlers have an assembly version of 14.0.0.0.  Using PowerShell I deleted all the Asynchronous event handlers for version 12.0.0.0 and I'm no longer getting the error!  My guess is that the ItemAdded event receiver was being called twice and they were tripping over each other?!?!

Answer (score 2):

I typically get this error in a document library when changing the SPListItem.File and metadata on the very same item in one go. I cannot see from your question how you create the publishing pages that fail. So you might want to add some details on that.

For the scenario described above I split the process into two parts. E.g. first upload the SPListItem.File, read the item again, change the metadata and than update the item once more.

Comment: This happens when choosing Site Actions > New Page, then in the New Page dialog entering the page name and clicking Create.  The dialog displays a processing message for a while, then displays the error.

Comment: Are there any eventreceivers present on the library or contenttype?

Comment: There are no custom event receivers.  Using SharePoint Manager I can see there are some SharePoint event receivers attached to the Pages library Microsoft.SharePoint.Publishing.PagesListCPVEventReceiver and Microsoft.Office.RecordsManagement.Internal.UpdateExpireDate